# How to browse PostgreSQL tables in DB Navigator?

Tags: postgresql, webstorm

I'm trying to figure out how to browse the schema in the DB Navigator plugin for WebStorm. I have the PostgreSQL database connectivity set up and can run queries through the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up switching over to mysql using phpmyadmin as the admin interface.